# I am trying to send email through telnet using smtp protocol but facing error response after "MAIL FROM:"

Tags: email, networking, smtp, telnet

I tried to send email using one of mail server but its showing error can anyone help me?
[MX record lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGHGU.png)
[SMTP session transcript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IovUp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some servers SMTP are more picky than others about proper SMTP command syntax.
It is usually anti-spam measure in "Era of Spam".

Try the following syntax fixes:

- Remove space(s) between `MAIL FROM:` and sender email address
- Put sender adress inside `<>`

`MAIL FROM:<john.doe@example.com>`

Comment: yes you were right , thank you for your help but once i type msg again another error or message pops out saying:

550-5.7.1 [113.199.189.193] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized                                          550-5.7.1 to send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at                                           550-5.7.1 your service provider instead. Learn more at                                                                  550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError c10si2546688pgh.181 - gsmtp 

@AnFi

Comment: @aayushmalla Most likely your IP address is listed on some DUL or "DUL like" list (dynamicly assigned IP addresses) => it is no longer your "syntax error", it is receiving server anti-spam policy.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialup_Users_List

Comment: oh i got it thank you for helping, i think i can setup mailserver within my window to  
see how smtp work or is there any alternative way?